# 1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql

My SQL statement returns properly on my laptop's MySQL (Server version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)) but on my server (Server version: 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)) it returns an error.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE `mail_sent`='No' 
  AND `datetime` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY `contact_id` 
ORDER BY `datetime` ASC;
```

> 1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and
>   contains nonaggregated column 'shop.orders.id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: This query tries to select one RANDOM record from record group with the same `contact_id`. So the query makes no sense.

Comment: I'm only looking for unique contact_id

Comment: Then only ask for a contact id:  `SELECT contact_id FROM ...`

Comment: @anjanesh `SELECT DISTINCT contact_id FROM orders`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this problem due to `strict mode` enabled in your MySQL version. Kindly disable strict mode and try again.

To disable follow [How to turn on/off MySQL strict mode in localhost (xampp)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881773/how-to-turn-on-off-mysql-strict-mode-in-localhost-xampp)

**STRICT_TRANS_TABLES** is responsible for setting MySQL strict mode.

To check whether strict mode is enabled or not run the below sql:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

If one of the value is **STRICT_TRANS_TABLES**, then strict mode is enabled, else not. In my case it gave

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------+ 
|Variable_name |Value                                     |
+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|sql_mode      |STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION|
+--------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Hence strict mode is enabled in my case as one of the value is STRICT_TRANS_TABLES.

To disable strict mode run the below sql:

```
set global sql_mode='';
```

[or any mode except STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. Ex: set global sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';]

To again enable strict mode run the below sql:

```
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

If you don't what to disable `strict_mode` then you have to change your sql query to follow sql `standard`.

like this..

```
SELECT
   aggregated_column,
   aggregated_column,
   aggregation_function(column),
   aggregation_function(column),
   aggregation_function(column)
FROM
  TABLE
WHERE [CLAUSE]
GROUP BY [GROUP BY FIELD]
WHILE [CLAUSE]
ORDER BY
```

for your query..

```
SELECT 
  contact_id,
  min(mail_sent),
  min(datetime),
  max(datetime),
FROM `orders` 
WHERE `mail_sent`='No' 
  AND `datetime` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY `contact_id` 
ORDER BY `datetime` ASC;
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Please edit the **"Kindly disable strict mode"** with **"Kindly disable strict mode if you want this nonsense query to be allowed and potentially return insonsistent or non-existent results."**

Comment: 4 yrs - I am now updating my MySQL server without disable strict_mode.

Your second query works without `ORDER BY datetime ASC`.

`SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders GROUP BY contact_id ORDER BY datetime ASC;` returns

"ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'shop.orders.datetime' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: This is equivalent ? `SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders GROUP BY contact_id ORDER BY MAX(datetime) ASC;` - because this works.

Answer (score 4):

Another quick fix is to use `ANY_VALUE(contact_id) as contact_id` instead of only `contact_id` in your `SELECT`.

For example:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(contact_id) as contact_id, ANY_VALUE(mail_sent) as mail_sent, ANY_VALUE(datetime) AS datetime
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY contact_id
    ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Note that the field you group by (e.g. `contact_id`) must be selected with `ANY_VALUE(contact_id) AS contact_id`.

> You can achieve the same effect without disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY by using ANY_VALUE() to refer to the nonaggregated column.

Worth to read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 2):

Put the remainder of the columns (except `contact_id`) inside aggregate functions. In my limited experience, MySQL isn't completely consistent in how it handles non-grouped columns outside of aggregate functions. Best case, it's not deterministic.

Comment: That was fixed in later versions

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ yes, and the new strict settings produce the error the OP gets when used with queries that can return inconsistent/nonsense data.

Answer (score 0):

in Ubuntu 20+
add in

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

or in

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

[mysqld]
sql_mode = ""
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0
```

settings like this, no more working

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```